# i18n in Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, helper, rails-i18n

Heelo, Basically what i want to do is

I have a helper that that return the day name in week from an index, the base of fuction is the  hash Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK how can  localize these names? i already use a svenfuch i18n in pt-BR but i can apply in that part.
this is my helper:

```
    def weekDayName(dayNumber)
        weekDays = Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK
        weekDays.index(dayNumber)
    end
```

and here it is in the i18n:

```
---
pt-BR:
  date:
    abbr_day_names:
    - Dom
    - Seg
    - Ter
    - Qua
    - Qui
    - Sex
```

in the view:

```
<td><%= weekDayName(price.week_day)%></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

In the i18n:

```
 ---
 pt-BR:
   helpers:
     labels:
       monday: 'Segunda-feira'
       tuesday: 'Terça-feira'
 .. etc
```

In the view:

```
 <td><%= t('helpers.labels.' + weekDayName(price.week_day).to_s) %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`weekDays.index(dayNumber) index is deprecated; use Hash#key weekDAys.key(dayNumber)`

than set

application.rb

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:'pt-BR',:en,:pt]
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
```

config/locales/pt-BR.yml

```
 pt-BR:
   monday: Dom
   tuesday: Seg
   wednesday: Ter
   thursday: Qua
   friday: Qui
   saturday: Sex
```

restart the server

```
def weekDayName(dayNumber)
  weekDays = Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK
  day = weekDays.key(dayNumber)
  I18n.translate day, locale: 'pt-BR'
end
```